# How do I create a MySql connection in .NET 6.0 Program.cs vs .NET 5.0 Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have established a MySql connection in .NET 5.0 in `startup.cs`, but would like to do almost the exact same thing in a new MVC web app using .NET 6.0, and `startup.cs` is no longer a part of .NET 6.0. Below is the connection I used before, written in C#. How would I do the same thing in `program.cs` in .NET 6.0?

Code from .NET 5.0:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>((s) =>
            {
                IDbConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("behs"));
                conn.Open();
                return conn;
            });

            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

I know (i.e. strongly suspect) it is done using builder, but cannot quite get it to work.

Again, I suspect the solution lies in `program.cs`, somewhere here:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!